# Watermark and compress image - error: the image could not be displayed due to an error

Tags: php, compression, watermark

I am trying to find the solution for this code. I would like change (compress) the image and then add watermark. Can you please help me with this code. What am A doing wrong?. My code is like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['slika'])) {
    $slika = $_GET['slika'];
} else {
    $slika = "ni_posterja.jpg";
}

$source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($slika);    
$source_imagex = imagesx($source_image);
$source_imagey = imagesy($source_image);
$dest_imagex = 500;
$dest_imagey = 300;
$dest_image = imagecreatetruecolor($dest_imagex, $dest_imagey);
imagecopyresampled($dest_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $dest_imagex, $dest_imagey, $source_imagex, $source_imagey);

$source_image = $dest_image;

$my_watermark = imagecreatefrompng('../nastavitve/slike/logo_zascita.png');

$watermark_width = imagesx($my_watermark);
$watermark_height = imagesy($my_watermark);

$image_1 = imagecreatefromjpeg($dest_image);
$image_size = getimagesize($dest_image);

$wm_x = $image_size[0] - $watermark_width - 20;
$wm_y = $image_size[1] - $watermark_height - 20;

imagecopy($image_1, $my_watermark, $wm_x, $wm_y, 0, 0, $watermark_width, $watermark_height);

header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
imagejpeg($image_1,NULL,60);
```

Thank you,
Best regards

Comment: What is actually going wrong?

Comment: I got an error: the image could not be displayed due to an error. I got only black display and error on the top of display.

Comment: I found the solution. First I must save image and then read it again. Now it is working :). I add this line: imagejpeg($dest_image, $slika)

Comment: U can answer ur own question, do this so others know the answer.